Does the sumset of coprime integers with itself contain all residue classes if the modulus is odd?
Let $m$ be an odd positive integer, and let $S_m$ be the set of all positive integers $n \le m$ for which $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. My question:

Is it true that for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $b,c \in S_m$ such that $a \equiv b + c \pmod{m}$?

My thoughts: this would not be true if $m$ were even, as the sum of two integers both coprime to $m$ would then necessarily be even, which means that odd $a$ cannot be represented as a sum. On the other hand, if $|S_m|> \frac{m}{2}$, then the claim automatically follows, as (by a counting argument) for all $a$ a $b$ exists for which both $b$ and $a - b \pmod{m}$ must be elements of $S_m$. The latter implies that the result is true for all odd $m < 105$, since $m = 105$ is the smallest odd positive integer with $|S_m| < \frac{m}{2}$.
Furthermore, for some probabilistic evidence, even if $|S_m| < \frac{m}{2}$, we still have $|S_m| > \frac{cm}{\log(\log(m))}$ for some constant $c > 0$. This means that there are more than $m^{2 - \epsilon}$ pairs $b + c$ with $b,c \in S_m$, making it very likely that those sums contain all residue classes modulo $m$. Finally, I have checked the result up to $m = 10^5$ and it seems to hold so far, assuming my code is correct.

The answer is yes. Outline of proof:

By the Chinese remainder theorem it suffices to prove the statement when $m$ is an odd prime power;
The statement is easy to verify by hand for an odd prime power.

